# std::thread::hardware_concurrency is one , should I implement threading on my system

Tags: multithreading, c++11

When I `cout` `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` it gives 1.

But from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency)

> Returns the number of concurrent threads supported by the
> implementation. The value should be considered only a hint.

Is there any use in implementing threads on my system, if the target if only my system?

Comment: May I ask what CPU do you actually have? This might be a hint, but seems like it is likely wrong.

Comment: @tambre: Intel i5 3rd gen.

Comment: Could you be more exact? What model?

Comment: @tambre Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz,  CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2

Comment: It *should* have 4 threads if hyper-threading is enabled. Though probably depends on multiple factors. I'll post my answer soon.

Comment: Official Intel Website says 4 threads as well: https://ark.intel.com/products/72164/Intel-Core-i5-3230M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz-rPGA

Comment: hardware_concurrency is a function. Did you use ()? Often cout displays 1 if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) says, the value of it should only be considered a hint. Note that it should return 0 only when it is actually unable to compute the value for the available threads on the implementation. 1 **might** be the actual number of usable threads for your application.

Unfortunately the only real and good way to find out if it's worth to have threading for your application, is to actually implement threading and benchmark your application. Depending on your application workload and the implementation of threading in your application you may see either no change, a degradation of performance or an improvement in performance.

Make sure to consider the following questions before implementing/considering multi-threading in your application:

- Can your workload be parallelized?

  - Would you need a lot of synchronization locks/mutexes/etc? If yes, then it might not be worth it.
  - Maybe you can split the workload onto a GPU? Consider if your workload can fit into video memory and if it is fit for processing on a GPU.
- Would the estimated time for implementation of multi-threading be worth it?

  - Make sure to create a small test application that would somewhat represent your use case.
  - If your application before ran 5 seconds and is estimated to run 2 seconds after implementation of multi-threading, was the increase worth it?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you have forgotten the brackets!

cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency;

reports always '1' on my machine, but

cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

reports the correct number of cores.